# How to upload files to EC2 using a C# .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-ec2, scp, winscp

I'm using `scp` to upload files to EC2 Ubuntu instance using a private key (`.pem`)

```
scp -i <path to private key> "local-file" "user@host":/path
```

It's working fine on Linux, but I need to integrate it into .NET application.

One option is to use command line, but there is no exact alternate to `scp` on Windows which accepts SSH-2 private keys.

Comment: You will need to use something like this: http://sshnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Not to be overly simplistic, but could you just use FTP?

Comment: @Matt Most instances don't have FTP configured by default. The networking environment of EC2 does create some compatibility issues for FTP (only works in passive mode)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SFTP to upload files to EC2, you do not need to restrict yourself to the SCP.

Anyway, WinSCP .NET assembly supports both the SCP and SSH-2 private keys.

For details on connecting to EC2 with WinSCP, see:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_ec2

See the example code at:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#example

For a command-line equivalent, you can use PSCP:
https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter5.html

WinSCP also has command-line interface:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting